# Difference between while loop and for loop in C leading to output difference

Tags: c

I am writing a code for the function `maxCharToFront()` that accepts a character string `str` as parameter, finds the largest character from the string (based on ASCII value), and moves it to the beginning of the string.

Main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void maxCharToFront(char *str);
int main()
{
   char str[80], *p;
   
   printf("Enter a string: \n");
   fgets(str, 80, stdin);
   if (p=strchr(str,'\n')) *p = '\0';
   printf("maxCharToFront(): ");
   maxCharToFront(str);
   puts(str);
   return 0;
}
```

This is the function using for loop:

```
void maxCharToFront(char *str)
{
    int i, maxcharint=0, maxindex=0;
    char maxchar;
    for (i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
        
        if ( (int)str[i]> maxcharint){
            maxcharint = (int)str[i];
            maxindex = i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    for (i = maxindex-1; i>-1; i--){
        str[i+1]= str[i];
    }
    maxchar = maxcharint;
    str[0]= maxchar;
}
```

when I enter ab as input, it gives back ab as output for for loop.

This is the function using while loop:

```
void maxCharToFront(char *str)
{
    int i=0, maxindex=0, maxcharint=0;
    char maxchar;
    while (str[i]!='\0'){
        if ((int)str[i]>maxcharint){
            maxindex = i;
            maxcharint = (int)str[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    for(i=maxindex-1; i>-1; i--){
        str[i+1]=str[i];
    }
    maxchar = maxcharint;
    str[0] = maxchar;
}
```

When I enter ab as input, it successfully gives back ba as output for while loop.

However, I don't see a difference in my while and for loop since both transverses all the characters in the input string starting from str[0]. Why is there an output difference? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in for loop you increment `i` twice, once in for loop and once more later on `i++`

```
void maxCharToFront(char *str)
{
    int i, maxcharint=0, maxindex=0;
    char maxchar;
    for (i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++/*increment here*/){
        
        if ( (int)str[i]> maxcharint){
            maxcharint = (int)str[i];
            maxindex = i;
        }
        i++; // increment twice
    }
    
    for (i = maxindex-1; i>-1; i--){
        str[i+1]= str[i];
    }
    maxchar = maxcharint;
    str[0]= maxchar;
}
```